# Закрытые, защищенные и открытые поля

Tags: c#

Учусь по учебнику для школьников с [MSDN: C# для вундеркиндов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb330920(v=vs.80).aspx)

Раздел "Закрытые, защищенные и открытые поля".

Пример выдаёт ошибку

```
 class Animal
 {
     public string kindOfAnimal;
     public string name;
     public int numberOfLegs;
     public int height;
     public int length;
     public string color;
     bool hasTail;
     protected bool isMammal;
     private bool spellingCorrect;
 }

 class Zoo
 {
     Animal a = new Animal ();

     // Следующая строка будет выполнена успешно, поскольку классу «Zoo» разрешено
     // обращаться к открытым полям в классе «Animal»
     a.kindOfAnimal = “Kangaroo”;

     // Обе следующие строки НЕ будут выполнены, поскольку классу «Zoo»
     // не разрешено обращаться к закрытым или защищенным полям
     a.isMammal = false;           // Попытка обращения к защищенному методу
     a.spellingCorrect = true;     // Попытка обращения к закрытому методу
 }
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы всё работало? И вообще, у меня консольное приложение под C# не запускается без этого в 1 классе:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Animal Barsik;
    Barsik = new Animal();
    ...
```

Пишу так.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Animal
{
    string kindOfAnimal;
    string name;
    int numberOfLegs;
    int height;
    int length;
    string color;
    bool hasTail;
    bool isMammal;
    bool spellingCorrect;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal Barsik;
        Barsik = new Animal();

        Barsik.kindOfAnimal = "Cat";
        Barsik.name = "Кот Барсик";
        Barsik.numberOfLegs = 4;
        Barsik.height = 50;
        Barsik.length = 110;
        Barsik.color = "Black";
        Barsik.hasTail = true;
        Barsik.isMammal = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Yo!");
        Console.WriteLine(Barsik.color);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Zoo
    {
        Animal a = new Animal ();

        // Следующая строка будет выполнена успешно, поскольку классу «Zoo» разрешено
        // обращаться к открытым полям в классе «Animal»
        a.kindOfAnimal = “Kangaroo”;

        // Обе следующие строки НЕ будут выполнены, поскольку классу «Zoo»
        // не разрешено обращаться к закрытым или защищенным полям
        a.isMammal = false;           // Попытка обращения к защищенному методу
        a.spellingCorrect = true;     // Попытка обращения к закрытому методу
    }   
}
```

Выдаёт 6 ошибок: 
непредвиденные кавычки, недопустимая лексема = и опять про кавычки.

Comment: Что значит "параллельно расположить классы"?

Comment: “Kangaroo” что это за кавычки такие? Должны быть ""

Comment: кавычки исправил. Ругается на =

Comment: @andruhakotov потому что вы написали какую-то бессмысленную кашу. У вас код, который должен выполняться в каком-то методе, находится прямо в теле класса **Zoo**, благодаря чему вы получаете уйму ошибок.

Плюс еще в классе Animal вы зачем-то написали метод Main, который должен находиться  в отдельном классе, специально предназначенном для моделирования приложения, и в котором по-хорошему не должно содержаться вообще никаких полей (тем более, полей, моделирующих какой-то объект)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы внутри класса `Zoo` пишете исполняемый код. Объявите внутри него метод и уже внутри метода пишите код

```
class Zoo
{
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    Animal a = new Animal ();
    // и т.д.
  }
}
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!!! Смогу сделать учебные примеры. Куда без них, на них учимся.

Answer (score 0):

Странный пример, видимо, тут опечатка или, что скорее всего, пример не рассчитан на компиляцию.

Любая программа начинает свое выполнение с точки входа, для консольного C# точкой входа является функция ***static void Main()***, поэтому она должна быть обязательна в любой программе.

Класс состоит из полей (переменные) и методов (функции), который его описывает. При этом исполняемый код может располагаться только в методах. А в данном случае он просто висит внутри Zoo класса, что является совершенно неправильным, и такой код никогда не скомпилируется. Либо его надо переносить в Main, либо использовать методы внутри класса Zoo, либо использовать конструктор.

Но об методах и конструкторе вы узнаете только позднее. Так что советую просто читать дальше и не заморачиваться, главное хоть примерно понять, что такое public, private и protected.

Comment: Немного дополню.  
Кроме полей и методов, в шарпе есть еще аксессоры - это такие методы для доступа к данным, которые описываются прямо в свойстве (и которые, насколько знаю, при компиляции преобразуются в обычные методы).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в целом верно. Однако тут предложили решение проблемы.